# Are there any other alternatives to pyinstaller on yocto poky?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, yocto

I am unable install pyinstaller on Yocto angstrom.

Can anyone suggest how to install or suggest any other alternative I can use instead of pyinstaller?

If i try to install using pip i got following error:

```
pip install pyinstaller

Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.1.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpQ_0Ckx
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-SBb07L/pyinstaller
  Complete output (19 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zCrEfW/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zCrEfW/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zCrEfW/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 243, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-zCrEfW/overlay/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 63
      file=sys.stderr)
          ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpQ_0Ckx Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please use the code formatter for the outputs and include what you tried already

Comment: The project (pyinstaller) is not compatible with python < 3.5. You are running on python 2.7